# Why this difference between foreach vs Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel.foreach

Can anyone explain to me in simple langauage why I get a file about 65 k when using foreach and more then 3 GB when using Parallel.ForEach?

The code for the foreach:

```
// start node xml document
var logItems = new XElement("log", new XAttribute("start", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")));
var products = new ProductLogic().SelectProducts();
var productGroupLogic = new ProductGroupLogic();
var productOptionLogic = new ProductOptionLogic();
// loop through all products
foreach (var product in products)
{
    // is in a specific group
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(product["ProductID"]);
    var isInGroup = productGroupLogic.GetProductGroups(new int[] { id }.ToList(), groupId).Count > 0;
    // get product stock per option
    var productSizes = productOptionLogic.GetProductStockByProductId(id).ToList();
    // any stock available
    var stock = productSizes.Sum(ps => ps.Stock);
    var hasStock = stock > 0;
    // get webpage for this product
    var productUrl = string.Format(url, id);
    var htmlPage = Html.Page.GetWebPage(productUrl);
    // check if there is anything to log
    var addToLog = false;
    XElement sizeElements = null;
    // if has no stock or in group
    if (!hasStock || isInGroupNew)
    {
        // page shows => not ok => LOG!
        if (!htmlPage.NotFound) addToLog = true;
    }
    // if page is ok
    if (htmlPage.IsOk)
    {
        sizeElements = GetSizeElements(htmlPage.Html, productSizes);
        addToLog = sizeElements != null;
    }
    if (addToLog) logItems.Add(CreateElement(productUrl, htmlPage, stock, isInGroup, sizeElements));
}
// save
var xDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new XElement("log", logItems));
xDocument.Save(fileName);
```

Use of the parallel code is a minor change, just replaced the foreach with Parallel.ForEach:

```
// loop through all products
Parallel.ForEach(products, product =>
{
    ... code ...
};
```

The methods GetSizeElements and CreateElements are both static.

**update1**
I made the methods GetSizeElements and CreateElements threadsafe with a lock, also doesn't help.

**update2**
I get answer to solve the problem. That's nice and fine. But I would like to get some more insigths on why this codes creates a file that is so much bigger then the foreach solutions. I am trying get some more sense in how the code is working when using threads. That way I get more insight and can I learn to avoid the pitfalls.

Comment: Try to simplify your code as much as you can. Currently, your code contains lots of code that is most likely irrelevant to the bug, but it makes it hard for us to work with it.

Comment: Where did you define isInGroupNew, I can not see it, I gues it is out of the foreach scope right?

Answer (score 2):

One thing stands out:

```
if (addToLog) 
  logItems.Add(CreateElement(productUrl, htmlPage, stock, isInGroup, sizeElements));
```

`logItems` is not tread-safe. That could be your core problem but there are lots of other possibilities.

You have the output files, look for the differences.

Comment: logItems is a XElement class. How is this related with being thread-safe? Do you mean the method Add is not thread-safe?
But also if the method is not thread-safe, what the heck, there will be all different elements added. Why should this be an issue at all?

Comment: @royu It's an issue because when two threads call `Add()` at the same time, something unexpected can happen.

Comment: What is the reason it is not made thread safe by default then?

Comment: If a make the adjustment as proposed by Mecek then it works. So the Add method doesn't seem like a problem ...

Comment: You can only change a `foreach()` into `Parallel.ForEach()` when the code inside is thread-safe . Your code isn't, in multiple ways. You have to analyze all shared data and resolve the issues. I'm not sure why @mecek's answer works. Maybe it doesn't.

Comment: No mecek's answer is indeed not working.
Changing to code this:
`if (addToLog)
  var locker = new object();
  lock(locker)
    logItems.Add(CreateElement(productUrl, htmlPage, stock, isInGroup, sizeElements));`
should work?

Comment: Why doesn't that work. That makes it thread safe, doesn't it?

Comment: No, the `var locker = new object();` makes it useless. You need to find some tutorials on threading and locking. That's not going to happen in this comment trail.

Comment: OMG I already read some articles over the years. Now multiprocessors becoming mainstream the need for it is increasing. I really wonder how I get grip on this subject.Seems like I just can't get some concepts clear. My thinking is incorrect, I try to understand why the code in the -not threading style- is not working when changed in parallel code. Seems like I must make more changes to the code then I do now.

Comment: Seems like I need to make an array. Then loop through the products. Create per product xelements (standalone), add them to the array. Then after the paraller loop I have an array with all the elements and I can put those to the logItems. Ok, then my code will be working for parallism. The problem is still that I don't know how it's internals work and why now get's things right and in the other situation not -with my current code-. So I must play by the rules, that's ok. But I still miss the insights, so know how to play by the rules is the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the following parameters inside the foreach loop.

```
var productGroupLogic = new ProductGroupLogic();
var productOptionLogic = new ProductOptionLogic();
```

I think the only two is used by all of your threads inside the parallel foreach loop and the result is multiplied unnecessaryly.